# Vary the color intensity of bars per category of a seaborn 'catplot' based on y-axis value of the bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

For a single or a stacked *barplot* I can vary the color intensity based on the value by using `sns.color_palette("Blues", len(df['x']))` (it has its own issue that equivalent bars still have different colors, but thats a question for later). It looks like this -
[image]

Now I wish to do the same in *catplot*. Going through the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) it looks like `palette` ought to help, so I constructed my palette like -

```
palette={'A': sns.color_palette("Blues", 51), 'B': sns.color_palette('Reds', 51), 'C': sns.color_palette('Greens', 51)}
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` are the 3 different categories where the color intensity should change based on the value it takes on y-axis. I hardcoded the length of the categories for a quick solution.
This however doesn't work and the palette is not generated -
**Error -**

```
ValueError: Could not generate a palette for <map object at 0x7efc31a60358>
```

Sample data to test your code on -

```
       index category  value
0    1/22/20    A      30
1    1/23/20    A      20
2    1/24/20    A      20
3    1/25/20    B      5
4    1/26/20    B      10
5    1/27/20    B      15
6    1/28/20    C      2
7    1/29/20    C      5
8    1/30/20    C      7
```

Code for the same -

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20'], 'category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'value': [30,20,20,5,10,15,2,5,7]})
p = {'A': sns.color_palette("Blues", 3), 'B': sns.color_palette('Reds', 3), 'C': sns.color_palette('Greens', 3)}
sns.catplot(x='index', y='value', hue='category', data=df, kind='bar', palette=p)
plt.show()
```

Solutions using Matplotlib are fine too.

**EDIT** -
I think it boils down to correctly defining the color palette. I think this is how you define it -

```
p = {'A': sns.color_palette("Blues", 3), 'B': sns.color_palette('Reds', 3), 'C': sns.color_palette('Greens', 3)}
```

Where the keys are the unique values in `category`.

The existing code actually given one more error that I missed to mention -

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:......
```

I tried defining my color palette as follows, but I get the same error as above -

```
n1 = plt.Normalize(a["A"].values.min(), a["A"].values.max())
n2 = plt.Normalize(b["B"].values.min(), b["B"].values.max())
n3 = plt.Normalize(c["C"].values.min(), c["C"].values.max())

c1 = plt.cm.Blues(n1(a["A"]))
c2 = plt.cm.Reds(n2(b["B"]))
c3 = plt.cm.Greens(n3(c["C"]))

p = {"A": c1, "B" : c2, "C": c3}
```

where `a`,`b` and `c` are dataframes that contain the single category with its values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't understand the approach to use a map of strings to several palettes and why those would each have 51 colors. Did you try to use one single mapping like `{"A": "blue", "B" : "red", "C": "green"}`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 51 referred to the original dataset I was working with. For the demo I ought to have kept it 3. I am sorry for that. Also I am of the opinion that seaborn identifies the hue based on the category irrespective of it being string or integer, perhaps thats why I used it that way.

Comment: I am not bothered about how the palette is generated. The main concern is that the dataframe is very flexible and can be configured to ease palette formation if necessary. Eventually I need to see shades in the bars of each category based on what value it takes.